Trying to identify a martial arts movie where one team hand their medals to the other team
This was a martial arts movie, I remember that it was team-based: members of teams fight against each other one-on-one and win points for their team, the points determine the winning team in the end. However, I don't know if it was just two teams or multiple teams. I think it was an american movie, with the winning team being Asian and the other (or second-best) American. In the end, the winning team hand their medals to the other team, beginning with a severely crippled member of the winning team.
There was a dramatic scene where this crippled member of the winning team barely limps from one side of the arena to the other, handing over his medal, with other members of his team following.
There was also a scene, earlier in the movie, where one member of the "other" team, a white guy, has a limb injury (can't remember if it was hand or leg), and his trainer makes him focus on ignoring the pain so he can continue fighting, which he manages to do.
I think the movie should be a relatively well-known 80s movie (maybe late 70s or early 90s). Any ideas?

What kind of game was played in the tournament?

It was a martial arts movie as stated -- what kind of game do you think they played? :-)

No actually I have seen martial art movies where by martial arts they play football.Sometimes no conventional game but a game format, where players of teams kill each other to survive!

It could be Best of the Best with Chris Penn.

The already existing answer is accepted answer given by asker himself and your answer is just looks copy paste.
